# Equivalence of inequalities

Tags: inequality

I'm having trouble showing the following.

> If $a>b\ge 0$, then
>   $$\frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{ab}<1 \iff \begin{cases}a+b<2, \text{ or,} \\ a+b \ge 2 \text{ and } (a-b)^2 < 4(a+b)-4.\end{cases}.$$

If $a+b<2$, the left-hand side holds trivially. I'm having trouble with the bottom line on the right-hand side.

Here are some attempts.
\begin{align*}
(a-b)^2 &< 4(a+b)-4\\
(a+b)^2 &< 4(a+b)-4+4ab\\
(a+b)(a+b-4) &< 4ab-4\\
&?
\end{align*}

And in the other direction,
\begin{align*}
a+b &< 2(1+\sqrt{ab})\\
(a+b)^2 &< 4(1+2\sqrt{ab}+ab)\\
(a-b)^2 &< 4(1+2\sqrt{ab}) \le 4+4(a+b) & \text{GM-AM}\\
\end{align*}
[so close!]

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$(a-b)^2 < 4(a+b)-4$$
$$(a+b)^2 < 4(a+b)-4+4ab$$
$$(a+b-2)^2 < 4ab$$
Since $a>b>0$ then
$$a+b<2+2\sqrt{ab}$$